# Displayong image from server

Tags: java, image, file-upload

I want to display user profile along with the user image . I am successfully uploading image to server by using following code,

```
String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
            teacherInfo.setPhoto(name);
            try {
                File fileSaveDir = new File(uploadFilePath);
                if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
                    fileSaveDir.mkdirs();
                }
                item.write( new File(uploadFilePath + File.separator + name));
                System.out.println("Uploaded Successfully");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

now I want to display image which is stored in `uploadFilePath` , and here `uploadFilePath` is server path of eclipse. Can any one help me in this .

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="<%=uploadFilePath%>/<c:out value='${filename}'/>" width="114" height="110" style="float: left;"/>
```

Comment: K . . . how do I link it in src attribute of img tag . .

Comment: @Raghavendra where you want to show this? in swing or in web page?

Comment: in webpage , actualy a jsp page . .

Comment: my images are stored in this path , D:\SERPCode\APRIL\8 APL\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\QualsTechWeb\uploads

Comment: k . . file name I have to get dynamicaly from database . .

Comment: no it is not like that . . , I have created a folder in server so path is, D:\SERPCode\APRIL\8 APL\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\QualsTechWeb\‌​uploads

Comment: which server you are using?

Comment: ssltomcat. . and I got that path by code,   String applicationPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("");
         // constructs path of the directory to save uploaded file
         System.out.println(applicationPath);
         String uploadFilePath = applicationPath + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIR;

Comment: @Raghavendra if you have path in uploadFilePath variable then use edited answer.

Comment: can you share your jsp file? where you are displaying this image.

Comment: <div class="form-group">
   <label for="ncy" class="control-label col-xs-3">Photo :</label>
   <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
    
    <c:set var="fileanme" value="${teacherId.getPrevEmpDtl()}"></c:set>
    <% %>
    <img alt="photo" src="<%=uploadFilePath%>/filename" width="114" height="110" >
     <label for="ncy" class="control-label col-xs-8">
      ${teacherId.getPhoto()}</label>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

Comment: where is your uploadFilePath in jsp.

Comment: oh yes before that I have these two lines, <c:set var="fileanme" value="${teacherId.getPhoto()}"></c:set>
    <% 
    String applicationPath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("");
    String uploadFilePath = applicationPath + File.separator +"uploads";
    %>

Comment: If you are using <c:set> then see the edited answer to get it's value.

Comment: yes but use it like this and tell me is it working? And check the complete path by printing it if it's not working.

Comment: no it is showing following error, Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Attribute value (<%=uploadFilePath%>/<c:out value='${filename}'/>" width="114" 
  height="110" >) not closed.
 - Start tag (<img>) not closed.

Comment: I am getting path by , <c:out value="<%=uploadFilePath %>"></c:out> but not getting in  <c:out value="<%=uploadFilePath %>/${filename}"></c:out>

Comment: you are writing it wrong see my answer it's <%=uploadFilePath%>/<c:out value='${filename}'/>

Comment: No . . , I tried like this . . , no error but image is not displaying. . .

Comment: what is the value of <%=uploadFilePath%>/<c:out value='${filename}'/>

Comment: I am trying to display path as `<c:out value="<%=uploadFilePath%>/<c:out value='${filename}'/>"></c:out>` but it is showing error but in place of `src` I tried ur code it doesnt show any error but not displaying image . .

Comment: but if I tried only `<c:out value="<%=uploadFilePath%>"></c:out>` it will show the path upto `uploads` folder . .

Comment: print the value of " <%=uploadFilePath%>/<c:out value='${filename}'/>"

Comment: yes I was printing like this `<c:out value="<%=uploadFilePath%>/<c:out value='${filename}'/>"></c:out>` . . is it wrong

Comment: print it's value and console and tell me is it giving complete path till filename?

Comment: I am doing that only right , c:out will display on browser , if above stmt is wrong tell me how to print..